# PrestaShop : We can't start installation :( PrestaShop installation requires the zip extension to be enabled

Tags: php, installation, zip, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Good morning !!! I need to see if you can help me with a technical problem; I use cPanel and I'm installing PrestaShop, it gives me a Zip extension error (which I have installed in PHP extension and Pearl modules, I don't know what else to do ... Let's see if you can help me please. Thanks !!!! The work you do is fantastic! attached images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVaT6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJx6N.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYWCI.jpg)

Comment: Have you check via `phpinfo()` if the zip module is really installed and enabled? Have you restarted the webserver after installing the module?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using another Version of PHP on your Prestashop v-host where your ZIP-Extension wasn't installed to (You can have many different PHP-versions on a server)

Create a php file called `phpinfo.php` in your webroot and run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` open it in your browser and check if the zip extension shows up, and if not check the system path of the php interpreter. (You may also post the results of phpinfo here on so)

Also, if you're using PHP-FPM, try to restart the FPM Service `$ systemctl restart php-fpm` or reboot your Server